# How do I grant permissions to manage test plans in VSO?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, microsoft-test-manager

**I am unsure whether this is the correct stackexchange site to ask this question, however it *is* about software tools commonly used by programmers (sort of).**

---

I am collection administrator of 100s of .net projects that I have recently migrated from an on-premise TFS to VSO. I am receiving requests from developers to grant them permission to create/manage test plans.

Now, these developers are members of the "Developer" and "Contributor" groups and as such have the following permissions:

[image: vso permissions]

But even so, they are unable to create test plans (using Microsoft Test Manager 2013). I have searched throughout the VSO control panel and I cannot find out why my developers don't have permission to create/manage test plans.

Even the documention provided by Microsoft seems to fall short when it comes to managing permissions in VSO.

Any help is much appreciated. How do I grant my developers these permissions?

---

**Edit:** I should add that I myself am able to create test plans. I have compared my permissions in a given project with one of the developers and they are pretty much equal (with some unrelated exceptions like deleting projects).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can control the "Manage test plan" permission on [area node level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587(v=vs.120).aspx#Area).
Go to area part, right click on the area your test plans belong to and then click on "Security"

[image]

**Now you can grant rights for managing test plans:**

[image]

Comment: This does NOT work for me. Those settings were already set to Allow for all the users I am trying to get to the Test Case management.

Thanks Microsoft; looks like I am punting once again.

Comment: @iGanja please check if you really set this permissions for the area your test plan is assigned to.

Comment: @iGanja - Also, please check "Access levels" as indicated in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36628930/team-foundation-server-2015-cannot-create-test-plans

Comment: Areas dont seem to exist in VSTS.

Comment: Areas are now under the Work tab.  Then there are two sub placeholders: Iterations and Areas

Answer (score 7):

If the area "Manage test plans/suites" permissions are set to allowed as suggested above and you still can't create test plans, don't forget to adjust the Access levels of your user!

Basic users (which should be default) can't access the test case management even if they have the right permissions.

[image: TFS Access Levels]

Answer (score 1):

This does not work in the local install I have done. It is stating that advanced permissions is deprecated. And the link to learn more goes no where.

Answer (score 0):

For those that haven't found a solution even turning all the options provided in Elena's answer, you can check this out:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/80055/cant-add-a-new-test-plan.html

It seems that Microsoft ask you for a **subscription in order to manage test plans**. If the user doesn't have a subscription, even if you add him to the project administrator group, he **won't be able to create test plans**.