# Team Foundation Server 2015 Cannot Create Test plans

Tags: tfs

I'm running the latest version of TFS 2015 Update 2.

I'm trying to create a test plan as per this guide 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380763.aspx

Which suggests when I go to Test > Test plan there should be a green plus icon to create test plans and so on. However I don't see this...

[image: What I see in TFS...]

I've got all 'test' related permissions under Security & Areas Allowed for my user, yet this makes no difference.

Am I blind or missing something obvious?

Comment: Are you setup as a Basic or Advanced user?

Comment: Is there a way to find out, other than the 'Access levels' tab which I don't get?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to [Change access levels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/work/connect/change-access-levels) for your account to **Advanced**. If your account doesn't belong to Advanced access level, you won't be able to see the green plus icon.

Comment: According to that link, I should get tabs 'Control panel', 'Access levels', 'Extensions' and 'Agent Pools' in the administration context, yet I only get tabs 'Control panel', 'Legacy Extensions' and 'Agent pools'. No sign of a 'Access levels' tab... does this mean I'm a basic user or have Microsoft been moving stuff around?

Comment: That would appear to be correct, my user for accessing the web UI wasn't listed under the 'Administration Console Users' - doing this revealed the 'Access levels' tab which I could then add the user to the 'Advanced' level, which now allows me to add Test Plans... bit a faff but got there in the end. Thanks for your help.