# Visual Studio Team Services: Don't see Option to Create Test Plan

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-test-manager

How do i create Test Plan, Suites, and Test Cases in Visual Studio Team Services?

I don't see option to create Test Plan, Suite, or Test Case. Please see the Picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possibility :

1. You are no permission to manage test plan, follow this steps : [How do I grant permissions to manage test plans in VSO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31711815/how-do-i-grant-permissions-to-manage-test-plans-in-vso)
2. Your account type is no access to this feature (see here : https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-team-services-feature-matrix-vs) basic account can only executed tests, not create them. If you want create Test Plans you must link a MSDN subscription to your account and change your access level to **Visual Studio/MSDN Subscriber** on this page https://youraccount.visualstudio.com/_user

Comment: I am using basic account and it does not have that feature